# Can I override a CPT template on a per post basis with Gutenberg block editor?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, block-editor

I have a CPT defined in code called event, and there is a template file for the markup (single-event.php).

I am wondering if it is possible to override a post within the Event CPT with the Gutenberg block editor, instead of using the php template every-time, is this possible?

I would ideally like the template file to apply to all my CPT posts, except one or two of them, which will require much different display.

EDIT: I guess in a more generic sense I am looking for optional template functionality for a CPT. Ability to use the provided template, or ignore it and utilize the block editor with Gutenberg.

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.7 Custom Post Types have [supported custom templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types), just like Pages. So you could copy your theme's generic page template to a new template file, and add this to the top.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Block editor template
Template Post Type: my-post-type
*/
```

That will let you switch the template for your `my-post-type` post to a template that looks and works just like a normal page.